# Laravel 4.2 JSON response not creating formatted JSON

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm creating a JSON response with data from a Laravel 4.2 install. This is a simple loop through a model, and pushing data to an array. Then, I'm encoding that array, and attempting to return JSON to a route (/feed for example).

What is returned isn't auto formatted by Chrome or Firefox, so that leads me to believe that I'm not forming the JSON correctly.

See this as my example:

```
public function feed() {
    $feed = CalendarEvent::ordered()->visible()->get();
    $events = array();

    foreach($feed as $item) {

      $event = array(
        'event' => array(
          'id' => $item->id,
          'title' => $item->title,
          'date' => $date
        )
      );

      array_push($events, $event);

    }

    $json = json_encode(array("events"=>$events));
    return Response::json($json);

  }
```

It is formatted like this in Chrome/FF
[example of rendered JSON in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyqiP.png)

Answer (score 2):

Response::json() expects the un-encoded json array, just remove the json_encode line and:

```
return Response::json(array("events"=>$events));
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you!